# How do I select a random work from a list which was made by importing a .txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, random

So I have a .txt file which contains the name, abbreviation, nickname, and capital of each state in the United States per line.

I need to print the names of 5 random states on different lines, one below the other.
The text file looks like -

```
Alabama,AL,Cotton State,Montgomery
Alaska,AK,The Last Frontier,Juneau
Arizona,AR,Grand Canyon State,Phoenix
Arkansas,AK,Land of Opportunity,Little Rock
and so on...
```

I imported the file and put it into a list by splitting at the comma. I have a list of all the names in it. But when I run `random.choice(data2)` instead of getting a random word, I get a random letter. This means that the list is made of each letter as an element and not each word as an element.

My code -

```
import random
inflie=open("F:\\SKKU\\study\\ISS3178 - Python\\11\\StatesANC.txt","r")
for line in inflie:
    data1=line.split(",")
    data2=data1[0]
print(random.choice(data2))
```

I expect a random state name but what I get is a random letter from one of the state names.

Comment: You keep overwriting ``data1`` and ``data2``. ``data1`` is *one* list of name, abbreviation, nickname and capital *of the last state read*. ``data2`` is the first entry of said list, i.e. just the name of that state.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so should I get `data2=data1[0]` out of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the result to a list and then use `random`

**Ex:**

```
import random
data2 = []
inflie=open("F:\\SKKU\\study\\ISS3178 - Python\\11\\StatesANC.txt","r")
for line in inflie:
    data1=line.split(",")
    data2.append(data1[0])   #Append state

print(random.choice(data2))
```

Comment: So this code would add one word from data1 to data2 one at a time as the loop is run?

Comment: Yes it does. Try using `print(data2)` to see the content